# Changing data name for one status but not the others

Tags: sql

**UPDATE**

I am using sql in my repository to return some data. I am almost done putting it together (pretty proud since I dont really know sql) but there is one part I am stuck on.

A delivery truck (dt) can only have 3 statuses: Confirmed, Delivered, Completed.

The problem I have to solve is that we return only Completed and Delivered trucks. BUT the client wants 'Delivered' trucks to display as 'En Route'. I need some help with the syntax and the placement for this.

So what I need is something like:

```
IF dt.Status = 'Delivered' dt.Status AS 'En Route' ELSE dt.Status.
```

I am also not sure if I should put this where we are displaying the status, or if I should put this down at the bottom where we are filtering the statuses.

My Code:

```
FormattableString sql = $@"
        WITH cte_latestStatus AS
        ( SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT
                s.TenantId,
                s.DispatchId,
                s.DispatchHeaderId,
                s.RequestedArrival,
                s.EstimatedArrival,
                s.Status,
                u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName UserName,
                s.CreateDate StatusChangeDate,
                row_number() over(partition by DispatchHeaderId order by CreateDate desc) as rn
            FROM
                DispatchStatus s
                JOIN AspNetUsers u on s.CreateUserId = u.Id
        ) t
        WHERE t.rn = 1
        )

        select w.wellid,
            w.wellname, 
            wo.ErpId,
            wc.ContractorName + ' ' + w.RigNumber Rig,
            w.CountyParish County,
            w.State,
            d.type DispatchType,
            d.CreatedInSAP,
            u.LastName + ',' + u.FirstName OrderedBy, 
            ds.RequestedArrival RequestedDate,


            **dt.Status,**


            dt.DriverName, 
            dt.SwamperName,
            dt.TicketNumber,
            dt.DispatchTruckId
        from well w
        join Dispatch d on w.wellid = d.DestinationWellId
        join cte_latestStatus ds on d.DispatchId = ds.DispatchId and d.HeaderId = ds.DispatchHeaderId
        join DispatchTruck dt on d.DispatchId = dt.DispatchId
        join AspNetUsers u on d.CreateUserId = u.Id
        left join WellContractorRef wcr on w.WellId = wcr.WellId
        left join Contractor wc on wcr.ContractorId = wc.ContractorId
        left join WellOperatorRef wor on w.WellId = wor.WellId
        left join Operator wo on wor.OperatorId = wo.OperatorId
        --join DispatchItem di on dt.DispatchTruckId = di.DispatchTruckId
        where d.TenantId = {TenantId}
        and d.type = {deliveryType}


        **and and (ds.Status = 'Completed' or dt.status = 'Completed') 
          and (ds.Status = 'Confirmed' or dt.Status = 'Delivered')**


        
        order by w.wellname"
        ;
        var result = await context.SapDispatches.FromSqlInterpolated(sql).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        return result;
```

Comment: Could you mean `CASE WHEN (ds.status='Delivered' OR dt.status='Completed') OR dt.status ='Delivered' THEN 'En Route' ELSE dt.status END AS status` as the 5th-last entry in the SELECT list?

Comment: `and (dt.Status = 'Delivered') AS 'En Route'` what is `AS 'En Route'` supposed to do? Why do you have an alias there?

Comment: @marcothesane so I should have clarified, there is a top level which is Dispatch Status. We are also making sure `ds.Status` and `dt.status` match before we return it. The parallel at the top level for  `dt.status = 'Delivered'` would be `dt.Status = 'Confirmed'` so the first line is correct and is working correctly. Now we want to add `dt.status='Delivered'` as 'En Route'

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE WHEN` for the Status

```
CASE 
WHEN dt.Status = 'Delivered' THEN 'En Route' 
ELSE dt.Status
END AS Status,
```